# False negatives when removing rows from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several name lists that goes like this:

Timestamp Name   Code   Email

I want to sort these lists such that only the ones who entered the code correctly will remain. An example list is given here

```
timestamp                         name                   password          email
2021-03-05 14:35:30.966000        ****                        ZX211          ***
1  2021-03-05 15:08:36.417000     ****                         ZX211         ***
```

I blacked out names and emails for privacy reasons, but you get the point. Some people wrote the code(ZX211) incorrectly and they need to be weeded out. I wrote something like this. This was supposed to throw the incorrect ones to another dataset.

```
ana1 = pd.read_excel(oturum, 'ana_1')
ana1_new = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(ana1)
boyut1=len(ana1.index)
for i in range(0,boyut1):
sifreler=["ZX211","UT938","ZIW92","QVL34","PTCO2","MQL13"]
if ana1.iloc[i,2]!= sifreler[0]:
   ana1.loc[ana1_new.index[i]] = ana1_new.iloc[i]
```

This succesfully removes the rows with incorrect code, in this case "ZX211". However, it gives false negatives. It also removes some correctly written codes and codes which have a whitespace in front of it ( ZX211) vs (ZX211) for example. I dont understant what is wrong with it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without having the raw data, but you can simplify your code with boolean indexing, e.g.:

```py
ana1[ana1.password != sifreler[0]]
```

Here's a toy example:

```py
import pandas as pd

passwords = [
    'ZX211',
    'ZX211',
    '   ZX211',    # wrong
    'ZX211',
    '   ZX211   ', # wrong
    'UT938',       # wrong
]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['***'] * len(passwords),
    'password': passwords,
})
```

|  | name | password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | *** | ZX211 |
| 1 | *** | ZX211 |
| 2 | *** | ZX211 |
| 3 | *** | ZX211 |
| 4 | *** | ZX211 |
| 5 | *** | UT938 |

```py
df[df.password != 'ZX211']
```

|  | name | password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | *** | ZX211 |
| 4 | *** | ZX211 |
| 5 | *** | UT938 |

```py
df[df.password == 'ZX211']
```

|  | name | password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | *** | ZX211 |
| 1 | *** | ZX211 |
| 3 | *** | ZX211 |